# Xcode 11, Main Interface fixed with Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode11

Main Interface is not changing with another storyboard in Xcode 11, it always run with Main.storyboard after changing with another storyboard, I have checked "is initial View Controller" after using a View Controller in new Storyboard.

I have tested in Xcode 10, it was working fine.

Did I miss something in Xcode 11?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
In plist.
[image]

Comment: Did you change it in project settings?

Comment: @iPeter Yes, it is not working.

Comment: Can you please show both your storyboards with initial view controllers?

Comment: @iPeter added..

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Swift 5 with iOS 13**

> One more changes require in *info.plist* file under **Application
>   Scene Manifest** group.

[image]

Change name in **Application Scene Manifest** also.

**Additional:**
If you want to create the root window **without a storyboard**, you need removing the `Main storyboard file base name` and `Storyboard Name` item from **Info.plist**, and create the window programmatically in `SceneDelegate`:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        // continue to create view controllers for window
    }

    //......
}
```

Comment: is it possible to give something similar like $(PRODUCT_NAME) = bundle name, for storyboard name?

Comment: I find it very frustrating that in order to change the main interface entry point there is literally 3 items to change within xcode in order for this to work. From the previous version of swift this "scene manifest" never existed... im sure apple has their reasons for adding in another required field to changed... but still frustrating ... way more complicated than it has to be

Comment: What if I want to change it dynamically

Comment: What's the purpose of 2 entries in "Info.plist" file? Either it has to take the one in scene configuration or from the "Main storyboard file base name"

Comment: Hello, what if I don't delete those 2 from info.plist? but I change the SceneDelegate. Would it be unsatisfying layout (not work as expected).

Comment: @FarrasDoko Change in SceneDelegate works like a charm over ios13 and onwards. For below ios13 SceneDelegate not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change "Main storyboard file base name" to your storyboard file name.

Comment: i didn't get you.

Comment: there is a key in plist file and under "Targets" -> Custom iOS Target Properties "Main storyboard file base name". There default is "Main". So if you want any other storyboard, replace "Main" with your file name.

Comment: By selecting storyboard from main interface, in plist, it automatically changed. though i have edited my question and added the screenshot of plist.